# Can't see database in Android Virtual Monitor

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem seeing my sqlite database on the Android Virtual Monitor in Android Studio. I cant open the data folder. I'm using the emulator to run the app, but I'm getting this error:

> Can't bind to local 8606 for debugger`

I've tried killing the `adb` server and restarting it but it did not help. Why does this happen?

[image: Screenshot of my Android Virtual Monitor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change my emulator to API 23 and now I can see my database.